# Logcat error tagged DISPSYS

Tags: android, adt, logcat

I'm trying to debug an Android app with Android Developer Tools (Build: v22.0.5-757759) on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit using a real device (Cubot GT99).
When I run the code LogCat logs a lot of errors per second:

```
09-16 00:20:30.697: E/DISPSYS(133): error: wdma_output_width(720) is small than scl_out_width(936)!
09-16 00:20:30.714: E/DISPSYS(133): error: wdma_output_width(720) is small than scl_out_width(936)!
09-16 00:20:30.732: E/DISPSYS(133): error: wdma_output_width(720) is small than scl_out_width(936)!
09-16 00:20:30.761: E/DISPSYS(133): error: wdma_output_width(720) is small than scl_out_width(936)!
09-16 00:20:30.768: E/DISPSYS(133): error: wdma_output_width(720) is small than scl_out_width(936)!
09-16 00:20:30.785: E/DISPSYS(133): error: wdma_output_width(720) is small than scl_out_width(936)!
```

I really don't know from where it comes from but I'm sure that this error tagged "DISPSYS" doesn't come from the code I'm trying to run.

Do you have any clue?

Comment: Are there any effects that the error has (crash, etc)? If it doesn't effect the app, I wouldn't worry about it...

Comment: There are no direct effects, but after few seconds LogCat console in ADT becomes cluttered with thousands of errors (always the same one) and it start removing older messages including the ones related to the code I'm debugging.

Comment: Is the device you're testing on rooted? Does this happen with other devices?

Comment: No, it's not rooted. Unfortunately I don't own other devices.

Comment: Searching for DISPSYS in the files of the default ROM for my device [(downloadable here)](http://www.cubot.net/Service.aspx?classId=6) I found that this tag is used in different files under the folder system/lib/. Now we know from where it comes from but there's nothing I can do about it. Is there a way to suppress the logging in LogCat of this particular tag? Using a simple filter fails because of the huge amount of errors.

Comment: Can't you filter the logcat to only look at your app? I've never actually told it to do it, but in Eclipse it seems to automatically make the filter when you debug the app...

Comment: I have the same problem with my phone (Mediatek clone with Android 4.2) when I use camera object in my application.